# Whether or not to use Markov's formula

Tags: probability

This is a question given on my last assignment.

"Suppose X is a random variable that never takes values less than 0 and has expectation E(X)=7.

Which of the following statements is always true?
Select one:

a. P(X ≥ 21) ≤ 1/3.

b. P(X = 21) = 1/3.

c. P(X = 7) > 0.

d. P(X = 28) = 1/4.

e. P(X ≤ 28) ≤ 1/4."

I am assumed that I could plug these numbers in Markov's formula. However, they all seemed to be true. So obviously I did something wrong. Any hints?

Comment: what is Markov's inequality as you know it?

Comment: Hint: Markov's Inequality is *what*?  Hint 2: Have you considered that $X$ may be either *discrete* or *continuous*?

Comment: Markov =  $P( x > a) < \frac {E[X]}{a}$

Comment: what is given in the problem above that hints that X is discrete or continuous?

Comment: Would it be $a$? Since Markov only deals with (less than/ equal to) and (more than/equal to)..

Comment: Forget Markov. Suppose P(X >= 21) > 1/3 what would be minimum contribution to E(X) from this region?

Comment: As others have noted, Markov's inequality does not apply to P(something) = something, only P(something) > something, and, by extension P(something) < something. You really should be able to solve this wo Markov's inequality though.